# Determine if the supremum is finite

Tags: functional-analysis

> Let $f$ $\in$ $C[0,1]$ , let $F(x)= \int_0^x f(t) dt $ for $x\in [0,1]$. Suppose $F(1)=0$. Determine if the value $$\sup_{g \in C^0[0,1]}\frac{\int_0^1F(x)g(x)dx}{(\int_0^1G(x)G(x)dx)^{1/2}}$$ is finite, where $G(x)=\int_0^xg(t)dt$  for $x\in[0,1]$.

when I first see the condition for $F(1)=0$, I think that it will be integration by part, so we can simplifies(?) to   $$\frac{{(\int_0^1G(x)f(x)dx})^2}{\int_0^1G(x)G(x)dx}.$$
I take square to make thing more beautiful, also I think that it will be some norm property, can some one help me? thanks

Comment: What do you mean by supremum existing? Are you asking if it is finite or if the supremum is attained at some $g$?

Comment: I mean the finite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\frac{{(\int_0^1G(x)f(x)dx})^2}{\int_0^1G(x)G(x)dx} \leq \int_0^1[f(x)]^{2} dx \leq \|f\|_{\infty}^{2}$ by Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, so the supremum  is finite.

Comment: great ,thanks a lot